# Displaying the solution at each iteration by using CVXPY

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization

By using [CVXPY](https://www.cvxpy.org), I want to solve this simple convex optimization problem:-

min ||z||^2 subject to z = Ax - b where A and b are given

The code is as follows:-

```
x = cp.Variable(n)
z = cp.Variable(n)
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(z))
constraints = [z == A@x - b]
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
result = prob.solve(solver = cp.SCS, verbose = True)
```

And I got:-

```
===============================================================================
                                     CVXPY                                     
                                     v1.2.0                  
===============================================================================
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: Your problem has 20 variables, 1 constraint, and 0 parameters.
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: It is compliant with the following grammar: DCP, DQCP
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: (If you need to solve this problem multiple times, but with different data, consider using parameters.)
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: CVXPY will first compile your problem; then, it will invoke a numerical solver to obtain a solution.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  Compilation                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: Compiling problem (target solver=SCS).
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: Reduction chain: Dcp2Cone -> CvxAttr2Constr -> ConeMatrixStuffing -> SCS
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: Applying reduction Dcp2Cone
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: Applying reduction CvxAttr2Constr
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: Applying reduction ConeMatrixStuffing
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: Applying reduction SCS
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: Finished problem compilation (took 1.690e-02 seconds).
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                Numerical solver                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: Invoking solver SCS  to obtain a solution.
------------------------------------------------------------------
           SCS v3.2.0 - Splitting Conic Solver
    (c) Brendan O'Donoghue, Stanford University, 2012
------------------------------------------------------------------
problem:  variables n: 21, constraints m: 22
cones:    z: primal zero / dual free vars: 10
      q: soc vars: 12, qsize: 1
settings: eps_abs: 1.0e-05, eps_rel: 1.0e-05, eps_infeas: 1.0e-07
      alpha: 1.50, scale: 1.00e-01, adaptive_scale: 1
      max_iters: 100000, normalize: 1, rho_x: 1.00e-06
      acceleration_lookback: 10, acceleration_interval: 10
lin-sys:  sparse-direct
      nnz(A): 117, nnz(P): 0
------------------------------------------------------------------
 iter | pri res | dua res |   gap   |   obj   |  scale  | time (s)
------------------------------------------------------------------
     0| 2.10e+01  1.00e+00  2.00e+01 -1.00e+01  1.00e-01  1.02e-02 
    50| 1.06e-12  1.28e-14  1.06e-12 -5.27e-13  1.00e-01  1.10e-02 
------------------------------------------------------------------
status:  solved
timings: total: 1.30e-02s = setup: 2.04e-03s + solve: 1.10e-02s
     lin-sys: 8.78e-05s, cones: 2.06e-05s, accel: 7.90e-06s
------------------------------------------------------------------
objective = -0.000000
------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    Summary                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: Problem status: optimal
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: Optimal value: 1.426e-30
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: Compilation took 1.690e-02 seconds
(CVXPY) May 03 09:50:28 AM: Solver (including time spent in interface) took 1.658e-02 seconds
```

**My problem**: I want to access the **solution** value x at each iteration.

As you see above, it's possible to get some details by using `verbose = True`. However, as I tried it with many solvers, it doesn't provide information about the solution to the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from CVXPY's output that your problem isn't very large. If that is indeed the case, one workaround would be to solve your problem iteratively in a loop, at each iteration setting SCS's `'max_iters'` option to the loop iteration number. See [this page](https://cvxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/advanced/index.html) for information on modifying the solver's settings.

Comment: Thank you for your help! In fact, I've already tried that. However, the solver makes an error when the number of required iterations to solve the problem is not enough, and thus most of the time I've got an error just from the first iteration.